# xslt with substring .i am failing in getting correct ouput

Tags: xml, xslt

I have return XSLT for getting output. Please correct this xslt if any thing is wrong

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<item>
<itemSale>
<xsl:if test="itemSale='abed' and itemsearch='bra'">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(itemSale,1,2)">
</xsl:value-of>
</xsl:if>
</itemSale>
</item>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output xml I want is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
<itemSale>ab</itemSale>
</item>
```

Input xml for testing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
<itemSale>abed</itemSale>
<itemsearch>bra</itemsearch>
</item>
```

but I am getting Output xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
<itemSale></itemSale>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your template matches `/` (the document root) and the only child element of that is `item`. `itemSale` and `itemsearch` are not children of the root, so `itemSale` produces 0 nodes and `itemSale = 'abed'` will always be false.

The two main options here are:

1. Match the document *element* instead (I recommend this):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/*">  <!--  here -->
    <item>
        <itemSale>
            <xsl:if test="itemSale='abed' and itemsearch='bra'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(itemSale, 1, 2)" />
            </xsl:if>
        </itemSale>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2. Use the whole paths to your elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <item>
        <itemSale>
            <xsl:if test="item/itemSale='abed' and item/itemsearch='bra'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(item/itemSale, 1, 2)" />
            </xsl:if>
        </itemSale>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: still I am getting <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><item><itemSale/></item>

Comment: I have tried with second solution which you have provided me.

Comment: JLRishe's answer is correct, and worked for me using xsltproc.  Did you run the provided XSL unmodified?